# Given two dictionaries, how do you overwrite matching items in one with items in the other, leaving the remaining items untouched

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Here is the starting code:

```
Dictionary<string,object> dest=...;
IDictionary<string,object> source=...;

// Overwrite in dest all of the items that appear in source with their new values
// in source. Any new items in source that do not appear in dest should be added.
// Any existing items in dest, that are not in source should retain their current 
// values.
...
```

I can obviously do this with a `foreach` loop that goes through all of the items in source, but is there some shorthand way to do this in C# 4.0 (perhaps LINQ)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foreach` is pretty small.  Why complicate things?

```
foreach(var src in source)
{
    dest[src.Key] = src.Value;
}
```

---

If you're going to repeat this often, you could write an extension method:

```
public static void MergeWith<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dest, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
    foreach(var src in source)
    {
        dest[src.Key] = src.Value;
    }
}

//usage:
dest.MergeWith(source);
```

---

As for doing it "with LINQ", the *query* part means that a LINQ method should have no side effects.  Having side effects is often confusing to those of us who *expect* no side effects from it.

Comment: I was just hoping that there was some shorthand way of doing it, that's all.

Comment: The extension method presented seems like the best solution to this problem, so I'll give you the checkmark...

Answer (score 1):

This one is rather ugly, but it does the job:

```
source.All(kv => { dest[kv.Key] = kv.Value; return true; });
```

Comment: You're welcome :-) I tend to agree with @Austin, though, probably best to avoid side effects in LINQ expressions.

Comment: `All` is used to determine if every item meets a condition.  In this context you could replace it with virtually any LINQ method; what you're trying to do is just use a `ForEach` method.  Make it easier on everyone and just use a foreach loop.  At the very, very least, use a `ForEach` extension method, rather than `All` as it's even more misleading.

Comment: The reason I gave this a +1 is because it illustrates the contortions one has to go through and the justification for writing a ```Merge``` extension method.

Comment: @Servy: Since LINQ does not provide a built-in `ForEach` method, I assume you are referring to a user-provided extension method. I suppose the [`MergeWith` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10886572/650012) by Austin fits this purpose just right.

Comment: [Writing a custom ForEach method is quite trivial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), and many people do it for every project, or use the `List.ForEach` method.